# How to upload a file/photo using katalon studio?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, browser-automation, katalon-studio

I'm trying to upload file using katalon studio for automation testing (web Testing. After clicking on 'Browse' button the windows popup is opened but i can't choose photo or go to specific path. I found a command **WebUI.UploadFile()** but I think I'm not using it correctly.

If anyone had something like this, please share your experience. How could i do this in katalon?

Answer (score 9):

You can give this solution a try:

1. Create the following custom keyword (https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Define+custom+keywords):

> ```
> import java.awt.Robot 
> import java.awt.Toolkit 
> import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection 
> import java.awt.event.KeyEvent
>
> import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword 
> import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject 
> import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
>
> public class WebUICustomKeyword { 
>     @Keyword 
>     def uploadFile(TestObject to, String filePath) { 
>         WebUI.click(to) 
>         StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath); 
>         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null); 
>         Robot robot = new Robot(); 
>         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
>         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
>         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
>         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
>         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
>         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
>         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
>         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
>     } 
> }
> ```

2. Replace 'Upload File' step with that custom keyword in your test case instead, e.g:

> ```
> CustomKeywords.'com.katalon.WebUICustomKeyword.uploadFile'(findTestObject('BrowseButton'), 'yourFileHere')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, create a keyword to the file upload button or link, something like: ***“Object Repository/Page_Add_Document_To_Current_Account/lnk_choose_a_file”***
2. Next, create a method call for which will handle the upload, like
   class uploadNewFile {

   /**
   This method will be used to upload file
   */
   @Keyword
   def uploadFileToTest(TestObject to, String filePath){
   WebUI.click(to)
   WebUI.delay(3) //i’d recommend adding this delay to give the code time to run
   StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath)
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null)
   WebUI.delay(2) //same reason as above

   Robot robot = new Robot()
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
      }
   }
3. Next, call the method where it needs to be in your code and it will appear something like:
   ***CustomKeywords.‘methodCalls.uploadNewFile.uploadFileToTest’(findTestObject(**null**), ‘’)***
4. Next, replace null in 3 above with the keyword you created in 1 above, then insert the filepath of the file to be uploaded into the ‘’ in 3 above.

The final statement would be something like:
***CustomKeywords.‘methodCalls.uploadNewFile.uploadFileToTest’(findTestObject(‘Object Repository/Page_Add_Document_To_Current_Account/lnk_choose_a_file’),
‘C:\Users\…\Documents\…\…\TestFile.txt’)***

All the best